# Equivalent of Hippomocks' previously existing MockRepository::ClassMock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, virtual, expectations, hippomocks

In the official version 3.1 of Hippomocks (https://www.assembla.com/spaces/hippomocks/wiki/Home) there used to be a `MockRepository::ClassMock` that constructed mocked objects (contrary to `MockRepository::InterfaceMock` that doesn't) which can be very useful when dealing with non-virtual class methods.

The current version's `MockRepository::Mock` does what `MockRepository::InterfaceMock` did in my opinion. Is there any possibility to construct mocked objects with the current version?

Rationale for my not taking the version 3.1: I need the also very useful ExpectCallFunc to test functions that don't belong to classes which was introduced later.

Rationale for not using placement new: Placement new would construct the object after being mocked by Hippomocks thus "resetting" the virtual function table previously altered by Hippomocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can mock methods and members now, which as far as I could tell should catch all cases where your class needs something to exist. You would use `MockRepository::MemberMock(obj, &Class::iValue)` to initialize the member.

If you really need `ClassMock` it's probably best to first think why you need it; in clean TDD it's never necessary so there's something that might need refactoring to avoid that situation. Then again, you can also backport `ExpectCallFunc`; it's a fairly separate functionality so it should be reasonably backportable. If you do though, take the current git version from Github as it has verified C method mocking for Linux/Windows/Mac X86 and X86-64 and on Raspbian/ARM.

Comment: The current Hippomocks version doesn't contain any `MemberMock` method. It contains a `MockRepository::Member` whose syntax I don't manage to decipher, especially the template parameter `class B` in `template <typename A, class B, typename C> void Member(A *mck, C B::*member)`.

Comment: As per the clean TDD I completely agree but I'm using a third-party software I won't be able to get changed in a short term.

Comment: Aah... that syntax is slightly confusing. The first argument is the object, the second is the address of the member. A is your class, C is the class of the member and B is the actual class of C's owner (which may differ from A, and is specified differently to ensure we can then convert the pointer to get a proper base offset). You should be able to specify `Member(obj, &Class::iValue);` to initialize it. After this it's fully initialized and usable so you should be able to just assign to it after.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have edited the answer to reflect your hints, please cross check my edit. I have eventually failed in initializing the member as it is not accessible from the test class. I'll check whether I can forward port the `ClassMock`.